# scala object composition - accessing nested object fields of different types (e.g. Array vs Option[Int])

Tags: scala, object, nested, composition, case-class

I am new to scala. be gentle. I have these nested object (I understand the OOP concept I am using is 'object composition', meaning an object inside an object)

```
case class T(na: Option[Int], du: Option[Int], sz: Option[Int], a: Option[Int])
case class BF(s: Int, a: Array[T], tr: Array[T], cs: Array[T])


val t = T(Some(1), Some(1),Some(1),Some(1) )
val bf = BF(5, Array(t), Array(t) ,Array(t))
```

This works:

```
bf.s
bf.a
```

I want to do:

```
bf.a.na
```

What is the problem?
regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bf.a` returns an Array of items, not a single item. You'll need to do something like this:

```
bf.a.map(_.na) // res0: Array[Option[Int]] = Array(Some(1))
```

This is saying for each item in `a`, return that item's `na` value. It's the equivalent of writing `bf.a.map(x => x.na)`